# Sqlite: is it possible to iterate select results in sql?

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreach, triggers

I have problem. I need trigger after insert. But trigger have to insert few rows depends on select from other table.

is it possibe in sql?

**Update:**

ok, sorry.

Example (no-logic) 
tables: 
users(id,name,type_user) 
type_user(id,type) 
items(id,name,type_user) - some type of users can posses only few items users_items(id,item_id,user_id)

And when i insert into users i want to insert into users_items all items which user can posses

Comment: Can you give us a little more information, example, any code you have attempted, etc. That is a little vague. There is a loop in SQL (I am about to get ostricized for bringing it up), but there is very little good use for it. Maybe your specific situation will work but we need more info.

Comment: Example (no-logic)
tables:
users(id,name,type_user)
type_user(id,type)
items(id,name,type_user) - some type of users can posses only few items
users_items(id,item_id,user_id)
And when i insert into users i want to insert into users_items all items which user can posses.

Comment: Please edit your question with this information instead of putting it in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Inside SQL Triggers you can do Insert statements.

You can find SQL Trigger information
[here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx).

Try something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER RelateItems
ON User
AFTER INSERT
AS 
--INSERT STATEMENT HERE - INSERT INTO users_items 
GO
```

Comment: I know that, but is it possible to insert values from select on other table?